# Gridview image from internet

Tags: android

I am trying to display image from internet in a Gridview. When I am running my program there is not error in the catlog but no image are displayed in my screen..

ImageAdapter.java :

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
Bitmap bmImg;
ImageView imageView;

public String[] mThumbIds = {
        "http://i724.photobucket.com/albums/ww246/bnhenson/squishy.jpg", "http://cdn4.teen.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/paranorman-zayn-malik-tweets.jpg",
        "http://xc0.xanga.com/08fe2b7a30c37281496919/m224298958.jpg"
};

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {         
    imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    downloadFile(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(135, 135));
    imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 1, 0);
    return imageView;
}
void downloadFile(String fileUrl) {

    AsyncTask<String, Object, String> task = new AsyncTask<String, Object, String>() {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            URL myFileUrl = null;
            try {
                myFileUrl = new URL(params[0]);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl
                        .openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.connect();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
        }
    };
    task.execute(fileUrl);

}}
```

AndroidGridLayoutActivity.java

```
public class AndroidGridLayoutActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
}}
```

grid_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/grid_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >  

</GridView>
```

And in my manifest I added this two line :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Does anyone have an idea, what step I miss here?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Germain.

Comment: You don't see anything at all or just the images don't appear in the cells of the `GridView`?

Comment: Yes the images don't appear in the cells, my "page" is white, nothing in it and nothing crash or stop..

Comment: Are you sure that the code in the `doInBackground` doesn't throw an exception resulting in the result bitmap being `null`?

Comment: I guess yes, I have nothing in my catlog and when i run my program in debug step by step, it don't catch exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a separate `ImageView` object for every cell of your grid, not use a global variable. To do so, so something like that:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext); 
    downloadFile(imageView, mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(135, 135));
    imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 1, 0);
    return imageView;
}

void downloadFile(ImageView imageView, String fileUrl) {
    // ...
    // change your AsyncTask so you can pass imageView as well
    // instead of setting loaded bitmap to global mImageView, set it to the passed in imageView.
    // ...
}
```

To change your AsyncTask, either change the type for `params` to `Object` so you can pass `imageView` and `fileUrl` to `doInBackground()` or create a class for your AyncTask with a constructor you can pass both objects and store them in variables local to the AsyncTask so you can access them from the `doInBackground()` method.

Also note that, if you have more items in your grid, you should reuse the passed in `convertView` when it has a non-null value.

Comment: Could you detail this : "Also note that, if you have more items in your grid, you should reuse the passed in convertView when it has a non-null value."? I don't understand this part

Comment: This is a very common use case with lists and grid views. Say you have a list with 1000 entries and only 10 are visible at the same time (due to the screen size). What android does to save resources is, that at first it only requests the first 10 items from the listview's adapter, not all 1000. Now when you scroll down the first line will scroll out of view as the 11th line comes into view. Now your getView() method gets the view of the now invisible line passed as `convertView` and you are supposed to use that view and tweak it to represent the 11th line, instead of creating a new view.

Comment: ... this way, only 10 view objects are needed to show a list of 1000 entries which avoids creating and deleting view after view, which is quite constly in android. There are a lot of better explanations for that and you should really get the grip of it if you want to program lists and gridviews efficiently.

Comment: Ok I get it. So I just need to add this to my code : if (convertView == null) {
  imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
  ..
  }
  else{
   imageView=(ImageView) convertView; 
  }